# Heroku app crashed h10 when deploying node js app

Tags: node.js, heroku, devops

Im trying to deploy simple CRUD node js API to heroku but always get app crashed h10,

It work in local https://i.stack.imgur.com/56GNF.png .But get this error when i deploy it https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbZzJ.png.

**Procfile**

`web:node app.js`

I am already tried `web: node app.js`, `web: yarn start`, `web:yarn start` and still got same error

**Package.JSON**

```
{
  "name": "servis-invoice",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon app.js",
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.18",
    "mongoose-delete": "^0.5.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

My config vars: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7f0K.jpg

**Is i am missing any steps?**

**I am using yarn but i dont know why heroku using npm start in deploy?**

Comment: My `Procfile` looks like this: `worker: node index.js`. Maybe it works like this for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the logs you see the (famous) error `web process failed to bind to $port` which means your application does not bind to the port provided by Heroku

Use `process.env.PORT` to define the port the application listens to

See [Heroku: Why is my Node.js app crashing with an R10 error?](https://help.heroku.com/P1AVPANS/why-is-my-node-js-app-crashing-with-an-r10-error) NodeJS documentation